# VueJs component doesnt show on a laravel blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to display a vue component which is in **assets/js/components/LoginComponent.vue** which look like this

```
<template>
<h1>hello</h1>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
 </script>
```

and the **app.js** is like this

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('login-component', require('./components/LoginComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app'
 });
```

and the blade which am trying to import my vuejs component is like this

```
<body>
<div id="app">


        <login-component></login-component>


        @yield('content')

</div>
</body>
```

it displays all the page without the component any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Don't forget npm run watch to actually build the component

Comment: @BennettDams No this is what I get https://imguh.com/image/8o6zy

Comment: @KhalidBakry Did you include `components: {login-component}` in your app component?

Comment: @BennettDams do you mean this line Vue.component('login-component', require('./components/LoginComponent.vue')); ?

Answer (score 0):

These solved the trick

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix

Install these and ctrl+s will rebulid all the js and will find it

Answer (score 0):

- Compile the Vue file with npm run watch or npm run dev.
- Check that you have the links to the the compiled assets on the blade file:

  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dist/css/app.css') }}">
  @if (app()->isLocal())
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  @else
    <script src="{{ mix('js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  @endif`
- Please check that them are loading correctly in the network tab,
- Also make the #app div only wrap the login-component

  `<div id="app">
    <login-component></login-component>
  </div>
  @yield('content')`

Answer (score 0):

In **app.js**

```php
Vue.component('login-component', require('./components/LoginComponent.vue').default);
```

and it is need to install 
`npm install --save axios vue-axios`

In Upper of **app.js** it is need to declare

```php
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
```

Hope it work